# Fluid Mechanics with calculus on manifolds

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

Fluid Mechanics is a branch of physics that uses a lot of vector calculus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to describe phenomena mathematically. Calculus on manifolds, however, is the straightforward generalization of vector calculus and has a lot of interesting and useful tools like differential forms, lie derivatives, flows of vector fields and so on.

Is there some book/article that treats fluid mechanics using calculus on manifolds? I've searched a lot for some book like this but I could only find one called "A mathematical introduction to fluid mechanics" which although uses a lot of math restricts itself to vector calculus. Is there some other book that uses the tools of the calculus on manifolds to describe fluid mechanics phenomena?

Comment: An informal place to start is this blog post: https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/fluid-flows-and-infinite-dimensional-manifolds/ . In it you'll find some relevant references, including the book "Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics" by Arnold and Khesin, which is a formal introduction to the connection between fluid mechanics and differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be quite what you're after, but "Relativistic Hydrodynamics" by Rezzolla and Zanotti covers (relativistic) hydrodynamics in the language of differential geometry.

This is a graduate level textbook on hydrodynamics in the context of general relativity (hence the differential geometry).  It covers kinetic theory (including quantum effects), wave propagation, numerical algorithms, and analytic work in the context of astrophysics.  You should have both some relativity and hydro under your belt before you tackle it, but if you do you may find it very useful.  It is also fairly recent (2013), so is very up to date.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather small section on the topic in the book "Differential Forms with Applications to the Physical Sciences" by H. Flanders. I don't find this extremely satisfactory, but what I'd do instead is take any book on fluid mechanics which has some consistent vector calculus notation and start "translating" it into the corresponding geometric notions. Perhaps Flanders can be of help at least in fixing a couple of ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score -3):

By "manifold", if you mean "flows along non-Euclidian surfaces" then there are several scientific but applicative papers online from the CG field, e.g. this one published at ACM Siggraph'03 / Transaction on Graphics: http://www.autodeskresearch.com/pdf/surfflow.pdf
( in this field papers are often 8 pages with figures and images of results, and since the domain is applicative a fair background in CFD should be ok to follow. But physical and numerical models often correspond to simple cases.  )

Comment: Hi Fabrice, please take a moment to read the [policy on answering this type of resource recommendation request](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698), your answer currently does not follow the expected format and may be deleted if you don't change it.

Comment: You mean, the "no dry ref" principle ? Should I really go deeper in details than "treats of flows upon non flat surfaces" ?

Comment: Yes, no simple links. As mentioned in the link I gave, your answer should cover (at minimum): What the book covers, how it covers it (rigoous? intuitive?) and its prerequisites.

Comment: is it better now ? ( scientific paper, but applicative, from CG field, published at ACM Siggraph/ Transaction on Graphics)

Comment: That's just added *where* you've found it, not *what* it is (i.e., it doesn't address any of the three points I mentioned).

Comment: What it is is "how to simulate fluids on curved surfaces". What is not clear ? It's an 8 page paper with images, easy to browse. What can I say more, beside starting to rephrase the paper itself ? If it's getting more complicated, I'll just delete my answer. Which is sad because it seems that information is noy so easy to find. :-(

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what wasn't clear about the three points I mentioned. For example, you could say, *This paper discusses numerical methods of simulating fluids on curved surfaces. It is a technical paper, but being 8 pages it should be an easy read. You'll probably need to know numerical fluid dynamics and some tensor calculus to fully understand it.*

Comment: re-re-edited. But, man, this guy asked about calculus on manifolds and differential forms: it's already clear he knows what tensors and CFD are. All this formalism seems gratuitous too me, especially knowing that he might not be interested by the aspect I mentionned.

Comment: While it is likely that OP knows what tensors and CFD are, your answer isn't for him/her, it's for the 100+ people who have the same question as OP & find this answer; you can't assume their knowledge is the same as OPs.